# How to post to local machine - Query, node.exe

Tags: jquery

I know there are a few questions/answers here already but none of them work for me.  I would like to post on my local machine a JQuery page but I can't get it working.

Here is an example, it just posts some results to a page on a server that doesn't exist but I don't know how to get it working on my local machine.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example</title>
    <script src="jquery-1.7.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jquery.tmpl.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

            var data = [
               { name: "Astor", product: "astor", stocklevel: "10", price: "2.99"},
               { name: "Daffodil", product: "daffodil", stocklevel: "12", price: "1.99"},
               { name: "Rose", product: "rose", stocklevel: "2", price: "4.99"},
               { name: "Peony", product: "peony", stocklevel: "0", price: "1.50"},
               { name: "Primula", product: "primula", stocklevel: "1", price: "3.12"},
               { name: "Snowdrop", product: "snowdrop", stocklevel: "15", price: "0.99"},
            ];

            var templResult = $('#flowerTmpl').tmpl(data);
            templResult.slice(0, 3).appendTo('#row1');
            templResult.slice(3).appendTo("#row2");

        });
    </script>
    <script id="flowerTmpl" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
        <div class="dcell">    
            <img src="${product}.png"/>
            <label for="${product}">${name}: </label>
            <input name="${product}" value="0" required />
        </div>
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Jacqui's Flower Shop</h1>
    <form method="post" action="http://node.jacquisflowershop.com/order">
        <div id="oblock">        
            <div class="dtable">
                <div id="row1" class="drow">
                </div>
                <div id="row2"class="drow">
                </div>            
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="buttonDiv"><button type="submit">Place Order</button></div>                    
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I was running node.exe on my machine and it was listening to a port number - basically listening to what what posted.

Is there any way I could post on my local machine, I have IIS installed but didn't get anything working.

**edit**

There is a script that goes with this called formserver.js.  I would run it with node.exe formserver.js.  I don't know how to post to local machine ?

```
    var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var querystring = require('querystring');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    console.log("Request: " + req.method + " to " + req.url);

    if (req.method == 'OPTIONS') {
        res.writeHead(200, "OK", {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "*",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
            });
        res.end();

    } else if (req.method == 'POST') {
        var dataObj = new Object();
        var contentType = req.headers["content-type"];
        var fullBody = '';

        if (contentType) {
            if (contentType.indexOf("application/x-www-form-urlencoded") > -1) {
                req.on('data', function(chunk) { fullBody += chunk.toString();});
                req.on('end', function() {            
                    var dBody = querystring.parse(fullBody);
                    writeResponse(req, res, dBody,
                        url.parse(req.url, true).query["callback"])
                });
            } else {
                req.on('data', function(chunk) { fullBody += chunk.toString();});
                req.on('end', function() {
                    dataObj = JSON.parse(fullBody);
                    var dprops = new Object();
                    for (var i = 0; i < dataObj.length; i++) {
                        dprops[dataObj[i].name] = dataObj[i].value;
                    }
                    writeResponse(req, res, dprops);
                });
            }
        }
    } else if (req.method == "GET") {
        var data = url.parse(req.url, true).query;            
        writeResponse(req, res, data, data["callback"])
    }

}).listen(8080);
console.log("Ready on port 8080");  

var flowerData = {
    astor: { price: 2.99, stock: 10, plural: "Astors"},
    daffodil: {price: 1.99, stock: 10, plural: "Daffodils"},
    rose: {price: 4.99, stock: 2, plural: "Roses"},
    peony: {price: 1.50, stock: 3, plural: "Peonies"},
    primula: {price: 3.12, stock: 20, plural: "Primulas"},
    snowdrop: {price: 0.99, stock: 5, plural: "Snowdrops"},
    carnation: {price: 0.50, stock: 1, plural: "Carnations"},
    lily: {price: 1.20, stock: 2, plural: "Lillies"},
    orchid: {price: 10.99, stock: 5, plural: "Orchids"}
}

function writeResponse(req, res, data, jsonp) {
    var jsonData;
    if (req.url == "/stockcheck") {
        for (flower in data) {
            if (flowerData[flower].stock >= data[flower]) {
                jsonData = true;
            } else {
                jsonData = "We only have " + flowerData[flower].stock + " "
                    + flowerData[flower].plural + " in stock";
            }
            break;
        }
        jsonData = JSON.stringify(jsonData);
    } else {       
        var totalCount = 0;
        var totalPrice = 0;
        for (item in data) {
            if(item != "_" && data[item] > 0) {
                var itemNum = Number(data[item])
                totalCount += itemNum;
                totalPrice += (itemNum * flowerData[item].price);
            } else {
                delete data[item];
            }
        }
        data.totalItems = totalCount;
        data.totalPrice = totalPrice.toFixed(2);

        jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);
        if (jsonp) {
            jsonData = jsonp + "(" + jsonData + ")";
        }
    }
    res.writeHead(200, "OK", {
        "Content-Type": jsonp ? "text/javascript" : "application/json",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"});    
    res.write(jsonData);
    res.end();
}
```

Comment: Start with changing action attribute of form element.

Comment: to what ? I was trying localhost: but was getting no where

Comment: On what port is server listening? How did you run node script (parameters)?

Comment: there was a formserver.js to go along with this (see edit above).  I had it listening on port 8080 on local host.... but I couldn't figure out how to post a page to my local machine/local host

Comment: What is response status at http://localhost:8080 or http://127.0.0.1:8080

Comment: {"totalItems":0,"totalPrice":"0.00"} its basically watching what gets posted. But it never changes because I can't get the post to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form method="post" action="http://localhost:8080">
```

Comment: thanks that works, but it doesn't use any of the formserver.js (the code in edit section)

Comment: Do you see any output in console?

Comment: I got a post value in the browser - {"astor":"10","totalItems":10,"totalPrice":"29.90"} and a Get/Post in the cmd console.  Only thing is that it didn't use any formatting - just the one line. but at least its working.. thanks !!!